# AC 3.0 - How can i place randomly a circle within another?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a project in which i make a small circle inside a big one. That small circle will be moving inside that circle randomly. I desire to find the border of outer circle and constraint the inner circle to be reflected by the border of outer circle.

The small circle is moving in different direction but when is hits the border of an outer bigger circle it then reflected.
sorry cannot attach image due to low reputations.
assume that the small circle is inside the bigger circle.

Comment: pls try to provide basic code or at least show us what you got/can do on your own and where you don't know how to solve the problem. Because right now this looks like: "here is my task, solve it for me"

Comment: Visual might help - if you drew the outer circle, you already know its radius and stroke weight.

Comment: he has no code to provide, he just want somebody to write it for him following his instructions.

Comment: i can do the same fact with square and a circle inside that square.

Comment: suppose circle is at the center of the stage. i make a AC like below c1.addEvnentLiestener(EVENT.FRAM, move); function move(e:EVENT ):VOID{    if(c1.x!=0){c1.x--; }else { //the circle is reflected when it hits on the wall of the stage along x-axis, that is what i want but with the circles not with stage or square. }} my code is working well as sketched above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that, with two circles named c1 and c2 on the stage:

```
var r1:Number = c1.width / 2; // big circle radius
var r2:Number = c2.width / 2; // small circle radius
var diff:Number = r1 - r2; // difference
var dist:Number = Math.random() * diff; // random distance between 0 and diff
var a:Number = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI; // random angle

c2.x = c1.x + dist * Math.cos(a); // coordinates of the small circle
c2.y = c1.y + dist * Math.sin(a);
```

Comment: it is not helping me,i request you to please review my problem once again.

Comment: @moon walker - I don't understand. By "reflected" do you mean that your circle should bounce?

Comment: yes sir, my program is pretty similar to the "win 7 bubble" Screen saver.